# Java get Files in Folder?

Tags: java, list, file

im trying to get the files in a dictonary including the type

like:

*src/mime.txt*

*src/pic1.png*

```
                    String path  = "dic images/";
                    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                        uploadFile(path   + "" + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                      } 
                    }
```

This didnt work cause with `listOfFiles[i].getName()` i get only the "pic1" withou the type or?

Comment: Because all you print is the name. Did you even look at the Javadocs?

Comment: You need to give a recursive call to folder

Comment: Define "didn't work". What does the directory contains, what do you expect this code to do and why, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Besides , what's the point off adding empty string ("") to the command???

Comment: Can't you get the file type just by the file extension? That will be the easiest, I think.

Comment: Get the path and take everything from last / (?)

Comment: Why don't you use `Files.walkFileTree()`? Or are you stuck with Java 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NIO.2 you can do this:

```
public void findAllFilesInDirectory(Path pathToDir) throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(pathToDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(file)) {
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

This print paths to all regular files in choosen directory. It also prints regular files from subdirectories.

Documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Answer (score 2):

use `getAbsolutePath` instead of `getName`

Try this:

```
File folder = new File("your path");//for example D:/java
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

---

One step further, if you need to print the full name of all the files in the subfolders too, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){//or whatever to call the printFiles for the first time

File folder = new File("D:/java");
printFiles(folder);
}

static void printFiles(File folder) {
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File f : listOfFiles) { 
        if (f.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else
            printFiles(f);
    }
}
```